# CMake custom command formatting issue

Tags: cmake, clang, llvm, llvm-cov

I'm trying to write a custom CMake command that will execute `llvm-cov` as a part of the coverage analysis. What I have is a string variable `tests` that holds the list of test executables and was defined as:

```
set(tests "\"path/to/test1\" -object \"path/to/test2\" -object \"path/to/test3\"")
```

Note that `-object` specifier precedes every test except the first one, since that's the format that **llvm-cov** expects. When I print that variable, I get:

```
"path/to/test1" -object "path/to/test2" -object "path/to/test3"
```

which is what I wanted to achieve.

However, when I create a custom CMake command like this:

```
add_custom_command(
        TARGET coverage
        COMMAND llvm-cov show -instr-profile ${profdata_file} ${tests} -format html -o coverage)
```

The command is not correctly executed since it expands to:

```
llvm-cov show -instr-profile path/to/profdata "/path/to/test1"\ -object\  "path/to/test2"\ -object\  "path/to/test3" -format html -o coverage
```

The problem is that backslashes are added for some reason before space characters. I've tried using `VERBATIM` and `COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS` options of `add_custom_command`, but neither worked. How can I solve this formatting issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've done is define the arguments all in one string together. And CMake faithfully passes it all as a single commandline argument (contributes +1 to "argc" and one single element to "argv" of the build tool that runs the command). That might not be a problem if the program parsing the command is written to deal with that, but it seems that in this case, the specific program isn't.

What you're observing the backslashes before the spaces is just the way that spaces are escaped so that it's not used as a separator between multiple commandline arguments and instead is treated as part of a continuous commandline argument in whatever tool is being used in your context.

I'm pretty sure what you want is to set `tests` as a [list variable](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#lists). Multiple value arguments to [`set`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html) get turned into elements of a list variable being set, and [unquoted arguments](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#unquoted-argument) are divided into elements in the same way lists are.

```
set(tests "path/to/test1" -object "path/to/test2" -object "path/to/test3")
```

And pass `VERBATIM` to your call to `add_custom_command` so that quoting things get passed properly to the build tool.

Note that (I think) technically you could pass `tests` as a quoted argument if you also pass `COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS` to the `add_custom_command` invocation.